# inner product between homogenous harmonic polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $v_i$ and $v_j$ are homogenous harmonic polynomials of degrees $i$ and $j$ respectively in $B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I'm trying to show for all $i\neq j$
$$ \int_{B_1} \nabla v_j \cdot \nabla v_i dx = 0.$$
I know
$$\nabla v_j(x) = r^{1-n}\nabla v_j(rx),$$ it then follows that for all $0<r<1$
$$\int_{B_1} \nabla v_j \cdot \nabla v_i \,dx = C \int_{B_{r}} \nabla v_j \cdot \nabla v_i \,dx$$
from a change of variables. By green's identity I get
$$\int_{B_{r}} \nabla v_j \cdot \nabla v_i \,dx = \int_{\partial B_r} v_j d_n v_i \,d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}=\int_{\partial B_r} v_i d_n v_j \,d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}.$$ I don't know how to proceed from here (vector calc not my strong suit). I've tried brute forcing through the gradients of $v_i$ dot with the gradient of $v_j$ in hopes of applying a symmetry argument to show why the integral would be $0$ but it got too messy and confusing notation wise so this is what I've got so far. Would appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $v_j$ is harmonic $$ \int_{B_1} \nabla v_i \cdot \nabla v_j \,dx = \int_{\partial B_1} v_i \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial \nu} \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}.$$ Since $v_j$ is homogeneous of degree $j$ on $\partial B_1$, $$\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial \nu} = x \cdot \nabla v_j = \frac{d}{dt} \bigg \vert_{t=1} v_j (tx) =\frac{d}{dt} \bigg \vert_{t=1}\big ( t^j v_j (x) \big )= j v_j(x). $$ Hence, $$ \int_{B_1} \nabla v_i \cdot \nabla v_j \,dx = j\int_{\partial B_1} v_i v_j \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}. \tag{$\ast$}$$ Similarly, since $v_i$ is harmonic and homogeneous of degree $i$, we obtain $$ \int_{B_1} \nabla v_i \cdot \nabla v_j \,dx = i\int_{\partial B_1} v_i v_j \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}. \tag{$\ast\ast$}$$ As $i \neq j$, ($\ast$) and ($\ast\ast$) imply $$ \int_{\partial B_1} v_i v_j \, d \mathcal H^{n-1} =0$$ and consequently $$ \int_{B_1} \nabla v_i \cdot \nabla v_j \,dx=0.$$

Comment: ahhhh I see. Thank you!